# magento no qty option in single product

Tags: product

In a same magento instance. One product has qty option, the other one doesn't. I have no idea why.

This one has qty option
[image]

This on has no qty option
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking at a non-simple product type such as `configurable` or `grouped`.

They do not have a proper quantity since they forward the check to their "children" products.